# <vector> push_back implementation internal

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, stl, push-back

In std::vectors push_back implemetation, when size()==capacity() , the part, that it allocates two times more place and copy the elements of old , I want to ask, the most effective way of that copying?

Comment: Could you please make your question more clear? Are you asking how do vectors copy the old elements and you want to do the same, or what?

Comment: I dont want to do the same, i want to know how vector do this ?

Comment: Then simply find the header file and look how it does it? My answer gives options on how to do it "most effectively". It does not describe what your std::vector<> implementation does, most likely.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really specified in the standard, but left for the implementation. Thus, different C++ library versions will do this differently. However, the `allocator` of the `vector` must be used for any allocation and de-allocations
(hence no usage of `realloc()`).

What the standard does specify, though is that if objects can be moved (instead of copied) then they should be moved (since C++11). Typically, a new block of raw memory will be allocated, typically twice the size of the previous, and then the elements moved (or copied and destroyed) from the previous to the old. For the generic case, this moving/copying must be done one by one (since otherwise the integrity of the moves/copied cannot be guaranteed without knowledege of the internals of the respective move/copy constructors). Of course, for pod (=plain old data) types optimisations via `std::memcpy()` are possible (and most likely implemented).

You can try to look at your C++ library implementation, but be warned that the code can be quite opaque to those unfamiliar with meta template programming: the code is complicated because of the various optimisations (for pod, movable types, etc.).

Comment: Right, I forgot about those forsaken allocators. When I did my embedded vector substitute classes with some extra stuff, I did not add allocators at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit as if you wanted to implement `std::vector<>` yourself.
The most efficient way is to avoid reallocations in the first place, which often but not always is possible.

If you have prior knowledge about how many items you will `push_back()` next, you can use `std::vector<>::reserve()` and avoid reallocations altogether.

If you really were to implement yourself, you might want to use `realloc()`, in spite of the fact that this is a horrible function which can do - depending on parameter values anything from `malloc()` to `free()` to `realloc()`.

The reason, why this function can be helpful is, that there is a good chance that there is still room behind the data block on the heap. `realloc()` is the only function which can avoid a 100% of the time moving of the data by expanding this heap blocks size, not touching the data at all, if there is enough room to do that.

The drawback of using `realloc()` is that your "special performance" implementation would forego the concept of allocators as well as fail to handle element types which require copy constructor calls etc. So you would best not name your vector vector but something like "SimpleDataVector" and possibly build in some mechanism to detect misuse.

Comment: Not if the implementation also uses placement new etc.

Comment: How should `realloc` know which placement-new to use?

Comment: If you look at std::vector implementations, you see that they, too make decisions on whether they move or copy. A similar logic can be applied using realloc, though it will be tricky as you cannot "ask first, decide later".

Comment: realloc() simply handles raw memory. If it had to copy the raw bytes of the block, it returns a different address. If it could keep the data in place, it returns the same address. This should be the criteria on how to "fix up" the content.

Comment: But there is no "I blit-moved the object, please fix it"-function. At all.

Comment: He asked for the "most efficient" way. So in some special cases, this will work. You usually cannot get both. "Most efficient" and "Generic". Even though I am pretty sure, that your class instances you put into a std::vector are also not aware about that they are being moved to new locations. Nor are they involved in the process, except in one case, when they are actually being copy-constructed during the move.

Comment: *"instances you put into a std::vector are also not aware about that they are being moved to new locations. Nor are they involved in the process"* - that's just wrong... the constructor and destructor functions are used to coordinate that while keeping the objects in a valid state.  For example, placement `new` may move- or copy-construct elements in a newly allocated, larger buffer before the old buffer's elements' destructor calls happen.

Comment: Yes, in some specific cases it can do everything needed, I never disputed that (trivial types, like I said). But you really should at least mention the conditions!